# Preserving instance variable values when using SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code execute on a timer.  The question I have is, could the values of the instance variables `mLatestBilletShopOrderNum` and `mLatestBilletItemNum` be overwritten by the last 2 lines of code before `retrieveLineItemResultsFromPCS()` is invoked on the event dispatch thread in the `run()` method?  If so, what would be the workaround?  Should I copy the values of those instance variables to `final` local variables before invoking `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, and pass those variables to `retrieveLineItemResultsFromPCS()` instead, as in Code sample 2?

```
if ( ( lShopOrderNum[ 0 ] != mLatestBilletShopOrderNum ) ||
     ( lItemNum[ 0 ] != mLatestBilletItemNum ) )
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            retrieveLineItemResultsFromPCS( mLatestBilletShopOrderNum, mLatestBilletItemNum );
        }
    } );
}
mLatestBilletShopOrderNum = lShopOrderNum[ 0 ];
mLatestBilletItemNum = lItemNum[ 0 ];
```

Code sample 2:

```
if ( ( lShopOrderNum[ 0 ] != mLatestBilletShopOrderNum ) ||
     ( lItemNum[ 0 ] != mLatestBilletItemNum ) )
{
    final int lBilletShopOrderNum= mLatestBilletShopOrderNum;
    final int lBilletItemNum= mLatestBilletItemNum;
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            retrieveLineItemResultsFromPCS( lBilletShopOrderNum, lBilletItemNum );
        }
    } );
}
mLatestBilletShopOrderNum = lShopOrderNum[ 0 ];
mLatestBilletItemNum = lItemNum[ 0 ];
```

Comment: Are you concerned by the retrieveLineItemResultsFromPCS() method overwriting the instance variables by assigning a new value to its arguments? If so, then no. Java passes references by value.

Comment: No, I'm concerned about the values of the mLatestBillet* variables being changed (by the code on the last couple lines of each code sample) before they get passed to `retrieveLineItemResultsFromPCS()`.

Comment: Another way to put my question is, are the values of instance variables referenced by the inner Runnable() class remembered at the time the inner class is constructed for use when `run()` is later invoked on the event dispatch thread (like the values of final local variables used the same way appear to be), or will inner class references to instance variables always use the value of those variables at the time the inner class method (run) is invoked?  If it's the latter, then the results of the first code sample are unpredictable.

Comment: You can also use `invokeAndWait` instead of `invokeLater`, then you wouldn't need to worry about the order in which things get called.

Comment: I thought of that, but there is a resource I'm using at the time that `retrieveLineItemResultsFromPCS()` will wait on, guaranteeing a deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Runnable` anonymous instance implements the `run` method. Only when that `run` method is executed, it reads the current values of the member variables `mLatestBilletShopOrderNum` and `mLatestBilletItemNum` and executes the method `retrieveLineItemResultsFromPCS`.

Therefore, the values of the parameters passed to `retrieveLineItemResultsFromPCS` depend on when the `run` method is executed.

If you need `retrieveLineItemResultsFromPCS` to not be affected by the last two lines, you should use your second approach, with the final local variables.

You can demonstrate this behavior to yourself by keeping the anonymous instance in a variable, and calling its run method before and after you change the instance variables :

```
...
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        retrieveLineItemResultsFromPCS( mLatestBilletShopOrderNum, mLatestBilletItemNum );
    }
}
runnable.run (); // will see the old values of mLatestBilletShopOrderNum and mLatestBilletItemNum 
mLatestBilletShopOrderNum = lShopOrderNum[ 0 ];
mLatestBilletItemNum = lItemNum[ 0 ];
runnable.run (); // will see the new values of mLatestBilletShopOrderNum and mLatestBilletItemNum 
...
```

Comment: I'm often lazy when I refactor a block of code into a Runnable for this purpose, letting the compiler tell me which code needs to change and variables need to be final.  In most cases where such code references instance variables it probably doesn't matter that it takes their value at the time the method gets run in the event dispatch thread.  In this case, however, it dawned on me that I might have a problem.  Thanks for the clarification.  Now if I just had an understanding of where local final variables referenced by an inner class live once the constructing method concludes...

Comment: @KevinRahe "a local class has access to local variables. However, a local class can only access local variables that are declared final. When a local class accesses a local variable or parameter of the enclosing block, it captures that variable or parameter." see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class)

Comment: I understand the rules.  What I'm more curious about is how it's implemented under the hood.  I'm an old-school C programmer, and my perception is that variables local to a method are allocated on the stack, and the stack pointer is reset at the conclusion of the method, effectively erasing the local variable values.  But in this case the value of (some) local variables is maintained after the method execution concludes.  So my question is, where do they exist at that point so they can continue to be referenced by a local inner class instance that persists?